# Difference between 8bit PNG and 32bit?

Tags: image, png

I have a PNG of the exact same texture and one is 8bit while the other is 32bit. They both look exactly the same to me, no quality changes. Can someone please tell me what the difference is between the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An 8 bit image will use 1 byte per pixel while a 32 bit image will use 4 bytes per pixel. The color bit depth refers to the number of bits used to indicate the color of a single pixel. More bits means a larger number of colors can be represented.

This wikipedia article may provide more information and a visual comparison of the difference. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth

A PNG image may also specify a palette of colors which could also be what the 8 bit/32 bit may be referring to. In this case, if it were referring to the palette, it's possible there would be no visual difference between the first picture and the second. Again, wikipedia has more information:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Color_depth

It's likely that there is a small visual difference between the images if they are not using an indexed color palette. However, as pst states in the comments below, it's possible they both look exactly the same.

Comment: That is, the 32-bit png *can* store more information; but loss would only occur if the 8-bit png *could not* represent all the information in the input (or rather, to the extent of the 32-bit png). A black and white image is a good example of the chosen color-depth (8 or 32) having no noticeable effect ..